# I am not able to create new app using "rails new blog"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

I am getting this error during create a new project so where will i add the thor gem version as explained in given duplicate question.

I am getting this error when i am trying to create a new rails application. I am also getting same error when i am running the command `rails -v`

```
umesh@umesh-Lenovo-G570:~/work/practice$ rails new blog
/home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/thor-0.19.2/lib/thor/parser/option.rb:130:in `validate_default_type!': An option's default must match its type. (ArgumentError)
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/thor-0.19.2/lib/thor/parser/option.rb:113:in `validate!'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/thor-0.19.2/lib/thor/parser/argument.rb:24:in `initialize'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/thor-0.19.2/lib/thor/parser/option.rb:9:in `initialize'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/thor-0.19.2/lib/thor/base.rb:544:in `new'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/thor-0.19.2/lib/thor/base.rb:544:in `build_option'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/thor-0.19.2/lib/thor/base.rb:278:in `class_option'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/base.rb:202:in `class_option'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:71:in `add_shared_options_for'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:160:in `<class:AppGenerator>'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:159:in `<module:Generators>'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:153:in `<module:Rails>'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/umesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
umesh@umesh-Lenovo-G570:~/work/practice$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "'Validate\_default\_type!': An option's default must match its type (ArgumentError)" when running Ruby on Rails generate on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823526/error-validate-default-type-an-options-default-must-match-its-type-argume)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the version of the thor gem that you use.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823471/rails-new-creates-a-validate-default-type-an-options-default-must-match-i) for more information. This question is a duplicate.